# ExtJS XTemplate replace specific occurrence in string

Tags: extjs, shopware

okay, so I am working on a shopware plugin and I need to change a `disabled` input field to a `readonly` field that has been defined in a XTemplate.

I have been trying to find a way to make this work but I just cannot come up with anything at all.

This code is a stripped down version, there are multiple input fields and some of which also are disabled, this is the last occurrence though.
Any hints are appreciated! :)

```
/**
 * Some function...
 */
createSomeFunction: function() {
    var me = this;
    return new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
        //stripped this down
        '<p>',
        '<strong>'+me.snippets.mediaInfo.adress+'</strong>',
        '<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="{path}" />',
        '</p>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
        {
            //formatting functions
            someFormattingFunctions: function(value) {
                //...
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

See the bit about readOnly.

Comment: I am trying to replace disabled="disabled" with readonly="readonly".
This piece of code, is from shopware so I cannot edit it directly, I'd need to override it but only replace this bit instead of the whole template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an override for the original Shopware view class to customize the template.

In your case it looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ShopwareOverride', {
    override: 'Shopware.view.Masterdata',

    createSomeFunction: function () {
        var tpl = this.callParent(arguments);
        //manipulate response of the original function here ...
    }
});
```

Since we now have access to the template, we can manipulate the HTML. Here you can call the [`set`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate-method-set) function to replace the template. It is important to pass the second parameter as `true`. This compiles the template again.
We can also access the original template which is available as a string (in `tpl['html']`). But beware, this part is not officially documented.

As a result, we can customize the template as shown here without changing the original code:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21e7